# How to add javadoc and sources for external Jars to Domino Designer?

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Domino Designer is based on Eclipse so I can change most of project's properties, like the build path and so on.

The Java team gives us a JAR to implement in our XPages and our managed beans but it's a pain to not have the javadoc and sources associated to help us in our code.

I tried to associate Javadoc and sources in "Project properties > Java Build Path > Librairies" to the JAR but it's lost when I save and re-open (the JAR is store in Code/Jars).

Is there another way to use a JAR and those resources ?

Answer (score 0):

Including the source code in the jars will work. That's what we do for OpenNTF Domino API.

Maybe by digging into the files in Package Explorer it would be possible to work out where it's set and automate setting it (possibly from xsp.properties or notes.ini or somewhere else) via a custom builder. Swiper on OpenNTF is an example of a DDE plugin that adds a custom builder.

Comment: It's possible to attach sources and javadoc jars if the library is store in WebContent and mentionned in build path. I store sources jar and javadoc jar in Resources/Files.

Comment: We are using Maven to generate .jar, I found a solution to include sources and Javadoc.